# Errors reporting on JSP using Struts tags

Tags: struts

I have created a small login application using struts and ibatis. Everything is working fine.
Validation errors are shown using  in my JSP page.
`<html:errors>` tag shows all errors at one place in a group.

I want to show errors in front of each html element associated with the particular error.

Is there any tag like `<html:error name="username" />`

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `<html:errors>` tag and the `<html:messages>` tag do that (in a different way). Read [their documentation](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#struts-html.tld)